# How can I create a pro-rated salary scale dictionary using a for loop?

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary, for-loop

somewhat new to Python here and wondering what the best way to accomplish this task would be. I am trying to create a dictionary that represents a pro-rated salary scale for a certain amount of days.

For example; day 1 salary = 1017781 and reduces by 5849 for each day after for a total of 174 days.

So the dictionary's key:value pairs would be formatted as `{day: salary}`

The first three key:value pairs should look like:

`{1: 1017781, 2: 1011932, 3: 1006082}`

So far I've tried something like:

```
dicts = {}
total_days = range(174)
day = 1
salary = 1017781

for i in total_days:
    day += 1
    salary -= 5849
    dicts[day] = dicts[salary]
```

But I am getting `KeyError: 1011932`

Any solutions to creating this dictionary?

Comment: Are you really using Python 2.7? If so, why? It's been past its end of life since the beginning of 2020. If you're just learning Python, learn 3 first, then go back later and pick up the differences between 3 and 2 later, if needed. By learning 2 first, you'll pick up a lot of bad habits that you'll have to unlearn later, and you'll write a lot of code that's incompatible with 3.

Answer (score 2):

Typo: I think it should be `salary` instead of `dicts[salary]`. Also, I would move the logic to increment / decrement the variables until the end of the `for` loop - see below.

```py
from pprint import pprint

dicts = {}
total_days = range(174)
day = 1
salary = 1017781

for i in total_days:
    dicts[day] = salary
    day += 1
    salary -= 5849

pprint(dicts)
```

Out:

```
{1: 1017781,
 2: 1011932,
 3: 1006083,
 ...}
```

---

Minor optimization when using `range(start, stop, step)`:

```py
dicts = {}
total_days = range(1, 175)
salary = 1017781

for day in total_days:
    dicts[day] = salary
    salary -= 5849
```

And, one step further with a `list` comprehension:

```
salary_delta = 5849
salary_start = 1017781 + salary_delta

dicts = {day: salary_start - salary_delta * day for day in range(1, 175)}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a dictionary comprehension (fancy way of creating a dictionary)

```
{day: 1017781 - 5849 * day for day in range(175)}
```

Comment: minor fix: I think it should be `* (day - 1)` instead of `* day`

Comment: I think it should start with salary 1017781 !

Comment: I just fixed it

Answer (score 0):

At first, the value of the third key in your dictionary is wrong. It is going to be 1006083.
Now coming to your problem, you need to understand how you create a new key in a dictionary and assign value to it.
When you wrote `dicts[day] = dicts[salary]`
Your dictionary created a new key called '2' but on the other side of the equal sign, you didn't assign a value, rather, you defined a new key that doesn't exist. So, the problem was you were assigning a key to a key.
When you assign a value to a key, you simply write the value or the variable that contains a value, for example, `dicts[day] = salary`
Now another problem was you had raised your variable's(Day) value by 1 before it got printed. So, you got the dictionary key from '2', not '1' and the same goes with the second value. So, you should be taking care of that as well.

```
dicts = {}
total_days = range(174)
day = 1
salary = 1017781
for i in total_days:
    dicts[day] = salary
    day += 1
    salary -= 5849
```

Answer (score 0):

try this,

- instead of declaring day and total_days as seperate variable you can use range() function where we can specify start and end of range.
- for each day salary will be deducted by 5489.

---

---

```
dicts = {}
salary = 1017781

for day in range(1,175):
    salary -= 5849
    dicts[day] = salary

#print(dicts)

# using Dictionary comprehension
dicts = { day:1017781 - (5849 * day)  for day in range(1,175)}
print(dicts)
```

Answer (score -1):

Here I have create the dynamic loop, which appling the changes on last items of dictionary and updating that changes.

```
dic = {1:1017781}

for i in range(174-len(dic)):
    dic.update({list(dic.items())[-1][0]+1 : list(dic.items())[-1][1]-5849})
```

Output:

```
{1: 1017781,
 2: 1011932,
 3: 1006083,
 4: 1000234,
 5: 994385,
 6: 988536,
 7: 982687,
 8: 976838,
 9: 970989,
 10: 965140,
 11: 959291,
 12: 953442,
 13: 947593,
 14: 941744,
 15: 935895,
.
.
.
.
```

Comment: Please give reason, if you think not useful !